# Making get requests to list of dictionary

Tags: python, api, rest, python-requests

i'm working with python and requests. My api data looks like as shown below :

```
[
 {
 'id_list' = [{'id':1,'name' = 's1'},{'id':2,'name' = 's2'}], 'username'='oiyio'
 }
 {
 'id_list' = [{'id':3,'name' = 's3'},{'id':4,'name' = 's4'}], 'username'='oiyio2'
 }
]
```

I can make request as the following :

```
http://api.example.com/users?username=oiyio
```

However, i need to check key **"id"** and retrieve the one with id=1 for example. How to do that?

I tried below one but it did not work as i have expected.

```
http://api.example.com/users?id_list?id=1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us some code? What exactly is not working for you?

Comment: 1) You need to identify what type of data structure that is and put it in your question 2) What code are you using to obtain that *api data*, post that

Comment: "the one with id=1 for example." Is this an *additional* condition to `username=oiyio` or an alternative? Do you want `users?username=oiyio&id=1` or only `users?id=1`?

Comment: @LutzHorn  I want to make a request such as users?id=1

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an API response, you need to modify the API code to return results as per the parameters requested by the client. If you cannot alter the API code, you have to change the code on the client side before consuming it. So, in your case:

```
for item in response:
    for data in item.getlist("id_list"):
        if data.get("id") == 1:
            print data
```

And if you have control over the API, you can always modify the API. You need to read the documentation of the API to know what all requests it caters to.